# Is <element>_has_next a legacy Freemarker syntax?

Tags: freemarker

Came across the follow line in a freemarker document for checking if there are more elements:

```html
<#list myList as myVar>...<#if myVar_has_next>...</#if></#list>
```

I know about the "?" for calling built-ins, and about "has_next", i.e. myVar?has_next.  What I am not familiar with using an underscore between the var and the built-in.  Is this a legacy syntax?

Comment: Are you sure that this works? I suspect a typo. [The docs](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html#ref_builtin_has_next) don't mention this kind of syntax and I personally have not seen this used ever

Comment: It works for sure. Quite the contrary, the one who wrote the template said if he changed it to "?", it failed with error:  Found has_next, expecting one of: is_directive, parent, js_string, j_string, uncap_first, is_transform, number, is_hash, trim, children, has_content, iso_ms, xml, iso_utc, byte, double, left_pad, matches, capitalize, number_to_datetime, contains, size, iso_local_h_nz, iso_utc_ms, iso_local_m_nz, is_collection, long, default, iso_utc_h_nz, iso_local_ms, is_boolean, last_index_of, c, iso_utc_m_nz, is_macro, rtf, iso_utc_nz, upper_case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is <del>an undocumented</del> a feature. The relevant code in [freemarker.core.IteratorBlock](https://github.com/apache/incubator-freemarker/blob/v2.3.24/src/main/java/freemarker/core/IteratorBlock.java#L307) shows that `myVar_has_next` is really just the name of a variable. But because the code checks for occurences of `_has_next` (and `_index`, fwiw) appended to the loop variable name (`myVar`), Freemarker is able to put a value to this variable.

At least with Freemarker 2.3.23, I cannot reproduce the error that you mentioned. The following code works just fine although it uses `myVar?has_next`

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TemplateException {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
    cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);

    Template template = new Template("test", "<#list myList as myVar>${myVar} <#if myVar?has_next>has next. </#if></#list>", cfg);
    template.process((Object) Collections.singletonMap("myList", Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")), new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
}
```

Produces

```
a has next. b has next. c
```

**Edit**: This feature [has been deprecated](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#autoid_107) in v2.3.23 (see @ddekany's comment)

Comment: Thanks for the revelation, moxn. Turns out, we are using v2.3.18, so ?has_next doesn't exist, which explains the error...

Comment: It's not an undocumented feature. See "Accessing iteration state" section on http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html

Comment: @Yiming Upgrade to the latest if you can. You are likely to waste developer time with that 5 years old version (because of less helpful error messages for example).

Comment: BTW, instead of `<#list ...>...<#if myVar?has_next>has next. </#if></#list>`, because it's a so common pattern, you can just write `<#list ...>...<#sep>has next. </#list>`

Comment: @ddekany, thanks for the pointer to the docs. I searched them for this variable but did not find it before. I have updated the post.

Comment: @ddekany absolutely. We will definitely upgrade and yes, <#sep> is a much terser notation.  Thanks everyone!!